# Effects of Reading the tablets en route to High Hrothgar?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

While walking towards High Hrothgar, I kept encountering few tablets that my my PC could read - it seemed like they were about the origins of Shouts. How many such tablets are there & are there any effects of reading all of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 10 tablets.  After reading the tenth, you get a "[Voice of the Sky](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blessings#Voice_of_the_Sky)" buff, which stops animals from attacking you or fleeing from you for one day.

Comment: yep, this is correct

Comment: When you say "buff" you mean it's a temporary effect?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie a buff is a temporary positive effect, while a debuff is a temporary negative effect.

Comment: Cool. I wasn't sure because you didn't mention how long it lasts. (A buff that expires by the time you walk back down isn't worth the bother of going up.)

Comment: the buff lasts for 23 hours...