# Get Woodland Grace in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the Knights of the Nine expansion for The Elder Scrolls 4: Oblivion you have to collect several of the crusaders relics. One of them is [The Boots of the Crusader.](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Boots_of_the_Crusader) These are enchanted with [Woodland Grace,](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Woodland_Grace) which turns most animals in the game into friendlies.

This is awesome and I loved having this ability in Oblivion. It's not like the animals where hard to kill or anything. I guess I am just an animal lover and enjoyed not killing them.

So is there anyway to get this enchantment or something similar in Skyrim? I am looking for something pernament as I already have a temporary solution in the shout of [Animal_Allegiance](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Allegiance).

Comment: I'm afraid I only know of the Animal Alleigence shout that does this but I'm curious if there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no enchantment effects or perks built into *Skyrim* that have this effect on creatures. It's entirely *possible* within the game engine, but it just wasn't done.

Because it's possible, it could be added in *theory* with DLC at some future date, or via a PC-only mod. For Xbox players such as yourself you can only hope that Bethesda chooses to implement something like this in future DLC, as they did with *Oblivion*.

Comment: As do I. It was an awesome enchantment before and I'd love to see it around again.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [this mod](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/10860). I personally haven't tried it but it seems as though it might help you if you don't mind something that may not be perfectly lore friendly or whatever.

Comment: Though that's useful for non-Xbox players, it doesn't help this asker.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/questions-where-op-has-mentioned-he-she-is-using-a-specific-platform-how-to-ans

Comment: @kotekzot I know, but as your own answer there says, it's OK to answer for *all* platforms. An answer that is only useful for one platform and not even the one the asker is using though? That doesn't solve the asker's problem.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie which would be a concern if only 1 answer was allowed to be posted per question.

Comment: @kotekzot Yeah, ok; post my own answer and leave it to votes, I know.

Comment: Definitely would be great for PC. Sadly, my PC isn't beefy enough for Skyrim.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a 24 hour solution as well already. If you read all the tablets on the way up to High Hrothgar you get a "voice of the sky" buff, which stops animals from attacking you. Not a permanent solution, but it is the longest lasting solution I've found thus far.

[I found the answer from this question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38559/effects-of-reading-the-tablets-en-route-to-high-hrothgar)